# Excel - hide subs from being displayed in the 'Customize Ribbon' dialog

Tags: vba, excel, add-in

Maybe a noobish question, but here it goes:

My goal is to install an Excel Add-in. 
I have all the code in a Module, organized in several `Sub()`s. I saved the Add-in in the Excel Add-ins folder. When trying to add the Add-in as a button/custom menu
(`File/Options/Customize Ribbon/Macros`), I see all `Sub()`s listed.

Is there a way to hide some of the `Sub()`s from being listed ? I only need the main one; displaying all of them becomes confusing when using multiple add-ins, especially since most of the `Sub()`cannot run be run by themselves. Are there any good practices for organizing the code in order to prevent this ?

Comment: Have you considered making the subs Private? With "Option Private Module" on top:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266185(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Vityata  Will the "Option Private Module" hide all subs by default ? So if I want a sub to be visible, I will need to declare it as Public ? I never used this kind of declarations

Comment: It would hide the private subs from being visible.

Comment: @Vityata Yep, that did the trick. If you formulate it as an answer to my question, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write Option Private Module on top and you make the subroutines private, they would not be visible.

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266185(v=vs.60).aspx) for Option Private Module.